# SIP Server for iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios4, voip

We have a social networking app on the iPhone. We now want to introduce VOIP capabilities into the app, we generally don't have much experience in VOIP but do have a lot of experience with iPhone dev.

We don't have the infrastructure to host our own SIP server so i guess we'll be looking for a provider which we can seamlessly integrate into our own system, in other words we don't want to have to create accounts on a providers server as we have in excess of 150,000 users.

What's the best approach to take? We don't mind paying either.

I guess if we can't get a provider we could potentially host our own SIP Server but as already mentioned, we don't have heaps of experience in that particular field.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may contact the company behind http://sip2sip.info service. Disclaimer: I work for that company.